# how can we call controller method from console kernel.php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how can we call `controller` method from console `kernel.php`  in `laravel`. I am going to schedule one `cron` to so in schedule method I have write some code and going to call `controller` method.
When I am going to call it and run the command `sudo php artisan schedule:run` It gives me **error** like

> [ReflectionException]   Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ReservationController does not exist

Comment: I know there are some questions related to this is already there. But they didn't help me.

Comment: Is the namespace correct? App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ReservationController. Usually Laravel controller are at App\ControllersReservationController.

Comment: Ohhh.. I forgot to remove Auth from the path. Thanks a lot @MuhammadTashfeen. You saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

Check your namespace. It should be `App\Http\Controllers\ReservationController`.